# Name of a threaded trunk panel fastener similar to a wingnut

Tags: part-identification, interior, fastener

I am looking to find replacements for missing fasteners that hold the interior trunk skin panels in a 2005 Chrysler 300. There are threaded studs in the interior of the trunk that these attach to in order to hold the panels in place.

They were similar to wing nuts but more like a plastic tube with full-length wings along the "tube" part and a built-in washer-like flange on one end.

My google-fu is failing me. I can't seem to find these parts anywhere and the folks at local parts stores don't know what I'm talking about. **What do I need to be asking/searching for to get my hands on some of these?**

Comment: Welcome to the site, a picture would tell about 250 words, why don't you edit and add one?

Comment: @GdD If I had one to take a picture of, I wouldn't have to buy new ones... or at least I wouldn't have to buy as many.... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for?

[image]

[image]

If so, the part number and description is: **Mopar Wing Nut 6507357AA**